# "I start making breakfast at 7" vs "I make breakfast at 7"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, difference

Tell me please if there is any difference between the following sentences.

> Usually I start making breakfast at 7 o'clock.
>
> Usually I make breakfast at 7 o'clock.

For that matter, is there any difference between

> I finished making breakfast at 8

and

> I made breakfast at 8?

If there aren't and differences, then which ones are more common?

Comment: It depends how elaborate your breakfast is! If you _start_ to prepare a full cooked breakfast at 7.00, it's no good telling the rest of the household that breakfast is at seven, but if breakfast is a bowl of muesli each, you could get away with saying "I make breakfast at 7.00".

Answer (score 1):

All three make sense in the proper context, and are equally likely.

Of course, without specifying "start" or "finish", the answer is less precise.

"Usually I make breakfast at 7 o'clock," could mean the speaker starts at that time, or, casually speaking, if you're a guest, come in for the meal at 7.